# How can use vue autonumeric input mask in nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I need input mask for money inputs and phone number inputs.

I tried this vue package and couldn't install it to nuxt3

https://github.com/autoNumeric/vue-autoNumeric/tree/master

I defined nuxt3 plugin in my plugins/moneyMask.js file

```
import {VueAutonumeric} from 'vue-autonumeric/dist/vue-autonumeric.min.js'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) =\> {
 nuxtApp.vueApp.component('VueAutonumeric', VueAutonumeric);
})
```

and used in template

```
            <VueAutonumeric
                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                v-model="contract.monthly_rent"
                :options="'commaDecimalCharDotSeparator'"
            ></VueAutonumeric>
```

but fails:

```
\[Vue warn\]: Failed to resolve component: VueAutonumeric
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```